# Several WPF- / XAML-Files performing better than a big one?

Tags: wpf, performance, xaml

I was talking recently to another GUI developer that was looking at one of my WPF applications. He suggested to break down my very large WPF views (files) into several smaller views. According to him this should promote loading performance as elements that are loaded from UserControls in separate files are rendered only when they actually come into view.
In my main view I currently have over 10k lines of XAML. As the main part of this view is a big TabControl with several large TabItems it would be easy to transfer the content of each TabItem into a separate file. It is true that most of the Tabs will not be used by every user or at least not directly after startup.

However, I was not able to verfy his claim by searching the web. Whenever I search the internet for WPF performance optimization I find all kinds of suggestions, but splitting up large XAML files into smaller ones was never mentioned in any way there.

For me, personally, having one big XAML per view is more comfortable and reusability is really not a problem in my case. So now I am wondering:

Would it really make sense to break my large views up into serveral small XAML files for each part that might not be needed at first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would it really make sense to break my large views up into serveral small XAML files for each part that might not be needed at first?

From a maintainability and reusability point of view, yes. But whether you define content of each `TabItem` inline or in a separate `UserControl` won't matter from a performance point of view.

So you won't gain any performance benefits of doing this:

```
<TabItem>
    <local:UserControl1 />
</TabItem>
```

...versus doing this:

```
<TabItem>
    <Grid>
       ...
    </Grid>
</TabItem>
```

You should consider adopting the MVVM design pattern and bind the `ItemsSource` property of the `TabControl` to an `IEnumerable` property of a view model and use `DataTemplates` to define the appearance of each item rather than defining everything inline though. Doing this, only the contents of the selected `TabItem` will be loaded into the visual tree.

Comment: Thanks for your input mm8. Using a list of UserControls to only have the selected one rendered did not come to my mind, although I use this technique in a differemt place already!